# Disable datepicker textbox conversion/validation on focus lost

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, datepicker

In the program I have one `DatePicker` that the user are allowed to not enter a date. But if the user enters one date and then he deletes it, the `TextBox` in the `DatePicker` does some kind of validation, and I want to disable that. Also, if I save the value after this "validation" the date entered before is the one saved.

[image: Image from Gyazo]

I have tried to set the date as null if it doesn't have any text, but that doesn't work.

```cs
private void PART_TextBoxFim_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Dp_DataFim.Text == null)
    {
        Dp_DataFim.SelectedDate = null;
        Dp_DataFim.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

Inside the class of the page I have this:

```cs
public Nullable<DateTime> Prop { get; set; }
```

The XAML of the datepicker is this one:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="Dp_DataFim" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,250,0,0" FontSize="16" Height="20" Width="230" SelectedDate="{Binding Prop}" IsTodayHighlighted="False" SelectedDateFormat="Short" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" IsTabStop="True" SelectedDateChanged="Dp_DataFim_SelectedDateChanged" Visibility="Hidden">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}" Background="#FF494949" Foreground="#FFEEEEEE" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="False" TextChanged="PART_TextBoxFim_TextChanged"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

I have noticed when this happens, I get a error like this one:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedDate; DataItem='DatePicker' (Name='Dp_DataFim'); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='PART_TextBox'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime value.
   em System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   em System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   em System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   em System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

Comment: You can't set a `DateTime` property to anything else than a valid `DateTime` value. Why are you binding to the `Text` property?

Comment: I'm binding because I want to be able to edit the time, like, I set the date/time with the button and after I want to correct the time.

Comment: There is `SelectedDate` property for this purpose.

Comment: ... ok, but I want to be able to delete the date and still be considered as a valid date, even if the user uses backspace to delete

Comment: How is a deleted date ever going to be a valid date? If you bind to a `Nullable<DateTime>` property, you can set it to `null` or a valid `DateTime`.

Comment: I see... and where do I set the datetime as nullable? Because this validation is something default of the datepicker, I haven't done this validation.

Comment: You bind the `SelectedDate` property to a `DateTime?` source property.

Comment: But where I do that? (And yes, I'm kinda new to WPF and programming with XAML :/ ).

Comment: In your XAML: `<DatePicker SelectedDate={Binding Prop}" />`.

Comment: so.. In XAML I have what is in the question and I added the `SelectedDate="{Binding Prop}"` in the `DatePicker` and in the C# I write `Nullable<DateTime> Prop;`? If is just that it didn't work...

Comment: `Prop` must be a public property: `public Nullable<DateTime> Prop { get; set; };`

Comment: I have edited the question so you can see if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Try to remove the `DatePickerTextBox`.

Comment: Well... Yes I think this works now, I have to do some things in the database and stuff, but it's possible to format the date as it is in the question?

Comment: You could use a converter. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `SelectedDate` property of the `DatePicker` to a `Nullable<DateTime>` source property.

If you change the format of the date by creating a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `DatePickerTextBox` where you bind its `Text` property to the `SelectedDate` property, you could then use a simple converter class to convert the empty `string` to a `default(DateTime?)`:

```
public class StringToDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const string DateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime? dt = (DateTime?)value;
        return dt.HasValue ? dt.Value.ToString(DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = value.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return default(DateTime?);

        DateTime dt;
        return DateTime.TryParseExact(s, DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) ? dt : default(DateTime?);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="Dp_DataFim" SelectedDate="{Binding MyProp}">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <local:StringToDateTimeConverter x:Key="StringToDateTimeConverter" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource StringToDateTimeConverter}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. :)